# Command Binding to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently struggling to get something to work, which in my head does not seem to be that hard.

A Got a TopLevel User Control which is displayed in a Window:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PCodeViewModel}">
        <controls:PCodeTabControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dx:DXTabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeader}" />
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MexCompileViewModel}">
        <controls:MexCompileTabControl  />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <dx:DXTabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"
                     ItemHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" />
</Grid>
```

The corresponding ViewModel is here:

```
private ICommand createNewProjectCommand;

    private string sandboxRoot;

    public MatlabBuildViewModel()
    {
        this.Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        this.InitTabs();
    }

    public void InitTabs()
    {
        this.Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModelBase>
                        {
                            new MexCompileViewModel(),
                            new PCodeViewModel()
                        };
        this.SandboxRoot = @"E:\_SupportTools\CaseManager";
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TabViewModelBase> Tabs { get; private set; }

    public void NotifyChildren()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new SandboxRootUpdated());
    }

    public string SandboxRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sandboxRoot;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.sandboxRoot = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                this.NotifyChildren();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the create new project command.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CreateEmptyProjectCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.createNewProjectCommand == null)
            {
                this.createNewProjectCommand = new DelegateCommand(Debugger.Break);
            }

            return this.createNewProjectCommand;
        }
    }
```

Now as you can see I am displaying two tabs by having a DataTemplate for the targetType MexCompileViewModel and PCodeViewModel.

Both userControls bound by a Dattemplate share a common UserControl which contains a number of buttons.

Here is the MexCompileTabControl as Example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <compositeControls:MexCompileGrid Grid.Column="0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <compositeControls:CommonActionsControl />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The CommonActionsControl is just a StackPanel with Buttons:

```
<StackPanel helpers:MarginSetter.Margin="3">
    <GroupBox Header="MatlabProject-File">
        <StackPanel helpers:MarginSetter.Margin="3">
            <Button Command="{Binding CreateEmptyProjectCommand}" Content="Create empty project-file" />
            <Button Content="Refresh" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Actions">
        <StackPanel helpers:MarginSetter.Margin="3">
            <Button Content="Clean" />
            <Button Content="Rebuild" />
            <Button Content="Generate m-Script" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
        public CommonActionsControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CreateEmptyProjectCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CreateEmptyProjectCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CommonActionsControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand CreateEmptyProjectCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(CreateEmptyProjectCommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CreateEmptyProjectCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

So what I am trying to achieve is:
My Commands are defined in the `TopLevelViewModel`. Now I want my `CommonActionsControl` inherit these Commands since the Control should be used multiple times. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `CommonActionsControl` displays common actions defined in the `TopLevelViewModel`, it would make sense to have them as part of the `TopLevelView` instead of displaying them on every tab.

If you really do want them on every tab, then I say your best bet is to add the commands to your `TabViewModelBase` so that the various tab views can bind to them. You're still free to implement them once in `TopLevelViewModel`, and just pass them into the various tab VMs by injecting them in the constructor.